# How to remotely upload a file using php to google drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have tried to use file_get_contents() and also curl to do this .. But both of these functions download the file temporarily to my pc and then upload to drive ...

Is there any way in which i can directly upload file from the url to my drive ?

Here is one code i tried :

```
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle('My app');
$file->setDescription('Application');
$file->setMimeType('application/exe');
$url = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);             
$data = curl_exec ($ch); // execute
curl_close ($ch); // close curl handle


$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array('data' => $data,'mimeType' => 'application/exe',));
```

Here is another one :

```
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle('My app');
$file->setDescription('Application');
$file->setMimeType('application/exe');
$url = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe";
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array('data' => $data,'mimeType' => 'application/exe',));
```

Both of these codes are downloading the files first to my pc ... then they start uploading

Comment: Please provide some code

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a URL in stead of a local file path to `file_get_contents()` or `curl_init()`, PHP will automatically attempt to download the file that the URL points to.

All you need to do to prevent this is to change the value of `$url` to a local file path:

```
$url = '/tmp/somefile.txt'; // *nix
$url = 'c:/somefile.txt'; // Windows
```

Comment: I did that .. But instead of the intended file .. the url is being uploaded as a text file (irrespective of the file type i choose) ....
I uploaded as an mp3 , and what i got was a 1 kb mp3 file in my drive .. When i opened with notepad i got the url link

Comment: It sounds like you're placing the path name in `$data`, in stead of doing `$data = file_get_contents($file_path);`. Also, to ensure that you're opening a local file, pass a file *path* rather than a *URL* to `file_get_contents()`. That means no "http://" or similar at the beginning.

Comment: I did that too...  And also file_get_contents()  only read a pointer to a file..   If I place the url in a text file and pass the file path of that text file to file_get_contents()  ,  the text file will be uploaded....  Not the file in the path name...